How to overwrite a variable imported from another module when running pytest tests?
I'm struggling to test the effect of changing the value of a variable stored in one module that is used in another. Here's a minimal example:
I have one script called settings.py:
from pydantic import BaseSettings, Field
class TestSettings(BaseSettings):
    TEST_BOOL: bool = Field(True, description="Test")
test_env = TestSettings()

In another script called lib.py:
from settings import test_env
def test_bool():
    if test_env.TEST_BOOL == True:
        print(TEST_BOOL is True)
        return True
    else:
        print(TEST_BOOL is False)
        return False

Now trying to use pytest to test the response from lib.test_bool depending on whether test_env.TEST_BOOL is True or False:
import pytest
import lib
from settings import test_env

@pytest.fixture
def set_env_test_bool():
    # Store the original value
    original_value = test_env.TEST_BOOL
    # Modify the value for testing
    test_env.TEST_BOOL = False
    # Yield control back to the test
    yield
    # Restore the original value
    test_env.TEST_BOOL = original_value

class TestFunctions:
    def test_test_bool_true(self):
        assert lib.test_bool() == True

    @pytest.mark.usefixtures("set_env_test_bool")
    def test_test_bool_false(self):
        assert lib.test_bool() == False

This sadly does not work - I get an assertion error: test_test_bool_false - assert True == False. I also see "TEST_BOOL is True" being printed.
What am I doing wrong? Why won't pytest use the fixture value of TEST_BOOL?
I have tried using various combinations of these fixtures but can't seem to get it to work.

Try importing the test_env object from settings.py dynamically into the test_bool function in lib.py.
As Python reads the import statement of test_env it executes the file and creates the object before test_bool function is called. When python modules are impoted they are cached. I guess that's what's creating a problem. You can read more about it here.
Try this:
In lib.py
def test_bool():
   from settings import test_env
   # Rest of the code

This will ensure that the latest version of test_env is used when your test_bool function is called.

Thanks for the reply! Sadly no joy, though - it still gives the same assertion error. Also, I'd prefer a different solution as in my real code the settings.env contains other variables used by lib functions so ideally I'd import them all together at the top. I will try and find a workaround to this
